# TFS2017.2 build definition update with REST API - custom process variable

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a simple build definition without build steps and with just a custom process variable.
[image]

Trying to update the variable through REST API with PowerShell:

```
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredentials
$definition.variables.aaa = "xxx"
$j = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 $definition 
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Body $j -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

will cause the removal of the variable from the build definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update `aaa's` value `bbb`  not the variable aaa itself.

```
$definition.variables.aaa.value = "xxx"
```